# C# Help converting this code from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Any help would be appreciated, I'm trying to convert the code below to C#, I've never used VB.NET so ReDim is a new one to me.

Thanks

```
Dim inFile As System.IO.FileStream
Dim binaryData() As Byte
Dim strFileName As String

strFileName = "C:\MyPicture.jpeg"

inFile = New System.IO.FileStream(strFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)

''//Retrive Data into a byte array variable
ReDim binaryData(inFile.Length)
Dim bytesRead As Long = inFile.Read(binaryData, 0, CInt(inFile.Length))
inFile.Close()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code could be converted verbatim, but there's a much easier way to achieve what this is doing (read all bytes from a file), i.e.

```
var binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(strFileName);
```

Personally I'd rename `strFileName` to just `fileName` as Hungarian notation is frowned upon in .NET code... but that's another matter!

Comment: Note: In older versions of .Net, replace "var" with "byte[]."

Comment: @Brain: No, in the pre-C#3.0 compiler replace var with byte[].

Comment: @Brian - you mean older versions of C#; you can still use "var" with .NET 2

Comment: @Brian - yep, cheers for pointing that out. I'm so used to C# 3.0 that I forget you can't use var in older versions!

Comment: Excellent example of a bad use of var.

Comment: @Stephen: How so? Even without Visual Studio I can tell that this function returns an array of bytes. What else could ***AllBytes return?

Comment: This use of var gains nothing at the cost of clarity. ReadAllBytes may *most likely* return an array of bytes but it could easily return an IEnumerable<byte> or something else entirely. This gratuitous obfuscation has become popular with the "cool kids" but it is a mark of sloppy programming.

Comment: @Stephen - That's your opinion and I think you're wrong, I'm afraid. It doesn't matter whether this is an array or a sequence, or even that it is bytes when it comes down to it. All that matters is that it is the data in the file.

Comment: Plus, if you're going to insult me by calling me a "sloppy programmer" then I'd love to see your justification. My justification for the use of var is here: http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2008/03/24/to-var-or-not-to-var-implicit-typing-is-the-question.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This very easy to convert to C#.

```
FileStream inFile;
byte[] binaryData;
string strFileName;

strFileName = @"C:\MyPicture.jpeg";

inFile = new System.IO.FileStream(strFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

binaryData = new byte[inFile.Length];
int bytesRead = inFile.Read(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
inFile.Close();
```

But there is a much better way to write this.

```
string fileName = @"C:\MyPicture.jpeg";
byte[] binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the ReDim statement is just used to initialize the array:

```
byte[] binaryData;

binaryData = new byte[inFile.Lenght];
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the *closest* translation would be:

```
binaryData = new byte[inFile.Length];
```

since it hasn't been assigned, or:

```
Array.Resize(ref binaryData,inFile.Length);
```

if it *had* been previously assigned. However, the code itself is **very** unsafe (you shouldn't assume `Read` reads all the requested data); a much simpler approach here is:

```
binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(strFileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're converting a lot of VB.NET to C#, you might want to check out [VBConversions conversion tool](http://vbconversions.net/).

Answer (score 1):

ReDim re-allocates the array.  Most of the time it's a code smell: a symptom or really wanting a collection type rather than an array.  This code should do what you want:

```
string FileName = @"C:\MyPicture.jpeg";
byte[] binaryData;
long bytesRead;

using (var inFile = new System.IO.FileStream(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read) )
{
    binaryData = new byte[inFile.Length];
    bytesRead = inFile.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)inFile.Length);
}
//I'm assuming you're actually doing something with each byte array here
```

Comment: @Joel - even this is a bit of a smell; it isn't safe to assume that a stream will read as much data as was requested; even for simple cases, a loop (checking the return from Read) is *technically* necessary. Most streams (including FileStream) are forgiving about this - but not all.

Comment: Yeah: fixed it so that bytesRead will still be in scope after the using statement.

Answer (score 0):

ReDim is used is resize arrays. (You can preserve the content if desired also. This code doesn't do that)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a permanant solution in case you need to do this again in future sometime.

Here are links for online VB to C# code converters and vice-versa. One is [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) and another is [here](http://converter.telerik.com/).

LinkText1: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/
LinkText2: http://converter.telerik.com/